# Countdown in days

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, counter

is it possible to create a simple javascript/jQuery countdown in days? I would like to create a daycountdown, but those on the internet are way to much. I just want something like this: Day 0: 300 days left. Day 1: 299 days left.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Do you want to input total days or a date?

Comment: If it is possible a date.

Comment: Does it help : var day = 300;
var intVal = setInterval(function(){
  day = day-1;
 if(day>0)   
 console.log(day);
    else{
      clearInterval(intVal)
    }
}, 1000*60*60*24)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a lot of code needed, just a small helper function to calculate days difference and then a replace content with whatever you want.

Full sample:

```
<html>
  <div id="counter" />

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function daysDifference($startDate, $endDate) {
      oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;
      return Math.ceil(($endDate.getTime() - $startDate.getTime()) / oneDay);  
    }

    // 2015/01/01
    $startDate = new Date(2015, 0, 1);
    // 2015/12/31
    $endDate = new Date(2015, 11, 31);
    $today = new Date();
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = 'Day ' + daysDifference($startDate, $today) + ': ' + daysDifference($today, $endDate) + ' days left';
  </script>
</html>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwjvqO?editors=100

Answer (score 1):

Try this and customize as your need:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var day=300;
    var interval=setInterval(function(){
       day -= 1;
       if(day==0){
           clearInterval(interval);
       }
    alert(day);   
    },1000);
</script>
```